# CSS cannot be loaded from `file:` URLs unless they end in a `.css` file extension

Tags: css, sass, loading

i'm trying for the first time to use sass and not css but when i try to load the stylesheet the browser tell me that it can only load .css as stylesheet.
Here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index_style.scss">
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

And the error

```
[Deprecation] CSS cannot be loaded from `file:` URLs unless they end in a `.css` file extension.
```

i'm using chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SASS is a preprocessor, the browser doesn't understand .scss, but only .css. SASS converts .scss files to .css.

There may be some projects that allow loading dynamically a .scss file "on the fly" from a HTTP server, but the message indicates that you are loading the page directly from your local file system.

In that case you need to invoke the preprocessor and point the `href` on the `link` to the generated file. It can be done directly with a command line command, with the instructions you can find here (https://sass-lang.com/guide) or if you are using a task runner like grunt, gulp, etc. there are task for Sass in those.