# How can I fix the Sass on my GitHub Pages site?

Tags: html, github, github-pages

So I'm coding on VS Code. I have Sass installed and I'm coding with it. When I view it in localhost, it looks how I want it to be. Then I upload it to GitHub and for some reason it is not working on GH Pages. Here is the link: [GitHub Dark Mode](https://leancoding.co/IR92DY)

I was trying to make a Dark Mode that I could add on my site. Here is the original tut CodePen that I followed: [The CodePen](https://leancoding.co/Z9JSAC). Do I have to convert it all to CSS?

Can you all please help?

Best,

NotDiamondZ

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the Sass file and call it on your html with .css extension instead of .scss

eg.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Perhaps you can check out this [CSS cannot be loaded from `file:` URLs unless they end in a `.css` file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60484685/css-cannot-be-loaded-from-file-urls-unless-they-end-in-a-css-file-extensio)